# Guard factory in nestJS application

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to create a [guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) factory in order to create a guard based on given params and ran into an issue.

I built the following factory

```
@Injectable()
export class GateKeeperFactory {
  public static guards = []

  static forRoute(allow: boolean) {
    @Injectable()
    class GateKeeperCustomGuard implements CanActivate {
      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        return allow
      }
    }
    const result = GateKeeperCustomGuard
    GateKeeperFactory.guards.push(result)
    return result
  }
}
```

and added the following to my `app.module.ts`

```
  providers: [GateKeeperFactory, ...GateKeeperFactory.guards],
```

To test this I created the following controllers

```
@Controller('/test1')
export class Test1Controller {
  @Get('1')
  @UseGuards(GateKeeperFactory.forRoute(false))
  test1() {
    return { in: true }
  }

  @Get('2')
  @UseGuards(GateKeeperFactory.forRoute(true))
  test2() {
    return { in: true }
  }
}

@UseGuards(GateKeeperFactory.forRoute(false))
@Controller('/test2')
export class Test2Controller {
  @Get('1')
  test1() {
    return { in: true }
  }
}
```

The issue is that all 3 routes are either blocked or all 3 are unblocked
I can assume that the `allow` param is shared between the guards for some reason I'm missing (I verified that 3 different guards are created)

---

Note 1:
according to the [guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) I know they offer a different approach of passing parameters to guards by using `SetMetadata` which at this point I want to avoid

---

Note 2:
Trying to add a constructor to the guards and using them as instances led to the error: `[ExceptionHandler] metatype is not a constructor` when loading the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're really looing for is what's called a [mixin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), a function that returns a class with a closure that allows the class to use the mixin's parameters. This is how Nest creates it's Passport `AuthGuard()`, btw. To take from your example above and tweak it a bit, you'd do something like this:

```js
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, mixin } from '@nestjs/common';

export function GateKeeper(allow: boolean) {
  
  class GateKeeperCustomGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
      return allow
    }
  }

  return mixin(GateKeeperCustomGuard) as CanActivate;
}
```

And now you should be able to use the guard like `@UseGuards(GateKeeper(true))`

Comment: I'm getting `[ExceptionHandler] metatype is not a constructor` with this approach

Comment: I'm getting the same error

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  Bit late to the party here.  Used this to create my own mixin guard and am having a hard time writing test cases.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to OP's 2nd note: ***"Trying to add a constructor to the guards and using them as instances led to the error: [ExceptionHandler] metatype is not a constructor when loading the server"***

The exported mixin guard must be a *function declared with the `function` keyword*, and not an *arrow function*.

In order to fix this, replace

```
export const BlaBlaGuard = (params: any) => { /* Guard class goes here */ };
```

with

```
export function BlaBlaGuard(params: any) { /* Guard class goes here */ };
```

in your code, and it should fix the issue.